# change attribute value in Core Data in already published application

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

*(Actually, I don't know how to formulate my question, so in google I found nothing.)*

So, the situation: In app in appstore I've the Core Data entity (let's say Weather), one of its attributes is Speed type String. Now it contains single line (e.g. 5 mps), but now I want it to contain an array-like string (e.g. 5 mps; 6.4 mps; ...) also change name from "Speed" to "SpeedHistory".

And I made a new model verison, chose it (it has little checkbox now), renamed the attribute, set "Renaming ID":"Speed" and now: how should I act, to prevent user's of old version data crash?

Could you give me some advice, please?

P.S. Data in Weather Entity is fulfilled by user. And I'm using MagicalRecord.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, no, but I am afraid of already existing info. Which is in different format

Comment: Well if you have renamed the attribute it any data in the old attribute will be lost when the store is upgraded.  Be sure to set the options to allow the store to be upgraded to the new version of the model.

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, so the previous data will be removed anyway?

Comment: Well if that's what you want then just create a new attribute called SpeedHistory and leave the old one as is or remove it, just don't use it in the new app or copy the data across to the new attribute when the app opens the first time .

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald, hmm.. create this in OLD database?

Comment: No you create the new attribute in the new model version so that when the new version of the app is used with an old database the old database gets upgraded and the old attribute get removed or ignored.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather common issue. When you update your model when using core data you have to migrate it. You can follow this tutorial which explains what you should do to fix your issue:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/27657

A lightweight migration is also relatively simple and can be performed safely. You only need to worry when the changes in your model kind of require a change in logic.

Comment: Thank for your advice!
Actually, I used this Ray's tutorial to make the migration.
The question is: how to delete value from "Speed" that was in old database(which now is "SpeedHistory")?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the type of a column is something that can't be done with lightweight migrations.  If you want to migrate the users' data when they upgrade to your new model version, you'll need to create a mapping model.  This process is described in the [Mapping Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMappingOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004399-CH5-SW1) section of Apple's *Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide*.

I haven't had much success with mapping models, as they seem to be very memory-hungry.

Have you considered adding the `SpeedHistory` attribute without removing the `Speed` attribute or setting a renaming identifier?  Then in your model class you could override `awakeFromFetch:`, check whether there's a `Speed`, and if there is then set the `SpeedHistory` as appropriate and clear the `Speed`.  You'll migrate the objects one at a time, on an as-needed basis.

Comment: Thank you for answer. As for "Changing the type of a column is something that can't be done with lightweight migrations." - The Type is still STRING, so I am talking about saving or deleting somehow the CONTENT of the old database. 
May be deleting is preferred, because in new database I'm working with this content.(it has now different format as I mentioned)

Comment: Ah, missed that.  If you're just changing the name of the attribute, you shouldn't be getting a crash.  Do you have details of the crash that you're getting, or are you just worried that you might get one?

Comment: I just tested, that there's no crash, BUT all the content of all attributes in Weather entity is deleted. Is there any way to prevent?